# How to check for a second instance of an app?

Tags: android, instance

I am trying to check if there is another instance of my app running. When starting the second instance, I am getting always that my app isn't running. The code for checking is:

```
public String NameActivity() {
  ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
  Iterator i = l.iterator();
  PackageManager pm = this.context.getPackageManager();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info =
    (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo) (i.next());
  try {
    CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(
      info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //Name Not FOund Exception
  }
}
return null;
}

public static boolean isThisProcessRunning(Context context, String processName) {
    if (processName == null) {
        return false;
    }
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {
        if (processName.equals(process.processName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **always** have only one instance of `Application` running. There may be multiple activities or services, but only one application. So, if you have any of your code running - it means your app is working, and it is just one instance of it.

Comment: so how to check if t one that langh the second how to check if the second is running already ?

Comment: Я не понимаю твой английский :)